# Is there a mode for Visual Basic (VB6) in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, vb6

I would like to use Emacs to edit some VB6 files but Emacs does not appear to have any of built-in niceties of other languages such as syntax highlighting, etc.

Any plugins/extensions? What else can I do to make Emacs an acceptable and comfortable IDE for VB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Visual Basic mode

http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/visual-basic-mode.el

edit: after installing this script (see script for instructions) syntax highlighting can be toggled via the options menu -- emacs calls it 'font-lock' :)

Comment: Very useful.  But there's a bug, at least in the version I found:  the line `(goto-cFormatCurrencyhar start)` should be replaced by `(goto-char start)` (I _think_...I'm not a LISP programmer).

Answer (score 3):

See these links:

- [xahlee.info](https://web.archive.org/web/20160429185744/http://xahlee.info/visual_basic/emacs_visualbasic_mode.html)
- [Emacs wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VisualBasicMode)

Answer (score 2):

For VB.NET, there is also a [VBNET mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VbDotNetMode).